# Error in using the function NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, system

I am trying to numerically solve a system of ordinary differential equations.

```
beta == 1.59*10^-6;
delta == 10^-6;
p == 23.91;
c == 10^-8;

system1 = {
    u'[t] == -beta*u[t]*v[t],
    i'[t] == beta*u[t]*v[t] - delta*i[t],
    v'[t] == p*i[t] - c*v[t]
};

initials = {
u[0] == 70000, i[0] == 0, v[0] == 7000};

NDSolve[{system1, initials}, {u[t], i[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

And when I run the code I get the following error:

```
NDSolve::nlnum: "The function value {17.0324,-17.0324,-0.00007+0.000177792\ p} is not a list of 
numbers with dimensions {3} at {t,i[t],u[t],v[t]} = {0.0000104385,0.000177792,70000.,7000.}."
```

I'm a complete beginner and I don't understand how to fix it myself. Similar questions didn't help me. Does anyone know how I can fix the code to make it all work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Set` instead of `Equal` (`=`, not `==`) for the initial four assignments:

```
beta = 1.59*10^-6;
delta = 10^-6;
p = 23.91;
c = 10^-8;
```

Your unchanged other definitions:

```
system1 = {u'[t] == -beta*u[t]*v[t], 
  i'[t] == beta*u[t]*v[t] - delta*i[t], v'[t] == p*i[t] - c*v[t]};

initials = {u[0] == 70000, i[0] == 0, v[0] == 7000};

nds = NDSolve[{system1, initials}, {u[t], i[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 100}];
```

And now for example:

```
Plot[{u[t]} /. nds, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh Eldo, thank you so much! So funny mistake))

Comment: You're welcome, mistakes like this one happen :)